# Calling same UserControl from another Page with different parameters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am having MainView.xaml file, where I am calling SubView.xaml file 2 times with Id as a parameter, like this,

```
<subView:SubView Id="1" Margin="12"/>
<subView:SubView Id="2" Margin="12"/>
```

According to this call, we will be having 2 different objects of SubView with Id = 1 and Id = 2.
I want to store both the objects at the time SubView.xaml is initialized first time and reuse them in the next call before initializing.

The problem is, SubView will get initialized with Id=null, Id will get value after sometime when set method of Id property will be called.

```
public SubView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public string Id { get; set; }
```

Please suggest me how to store 2 different objects in dictionary or any other thing, and how to reuse that again.
I don't want to store MainView.xaml file object. I am interested in SubView.xaml object only.

A lot of Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to archive? By your question i would try to use a ItemsControl, put your SubViews a List in the MainViewViewModel and bind the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl to the List. So you can control what/when your Subviews are loaded/Initialized/reloaded from the MainView's ViewModel

Comment: You are not "calling" SubView in your XAML markup. You *create* instances of it. And of course you have to instantiate the object before you can set any of its properties or use any other members of it. Storing two in a dictionary should be a no brainer. What do you mean "reuse them in the next call before initializing"...?